# Writing vector to linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Write the vector $$v=(2,-5,3)$$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as a linear combination of the vectors $$e_{1}=(1,-3,2),e_{2}=(2,-4,-1),e_{3}=(1,-5,7)$$
writing this as a matrix, \begin{pmatrix}
 1&  2&  1&2 \\ 
 -3&  -4&-5  &-5 \\ 
 2&  -1&  7&3 
\end{pmatrix} ~$\rightarrow$ \begin{pmatrix}
 1&0  &3  &0 \\ 
 0&  1&  -1&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&1 
\end{pmatrix} it seems like I couldn't find any $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}$ to express the vector as a linear combination.

Comment: Well, indeed the three vectors aren't linearly independent...

Comment: Sometimes the solution is that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are not linearly independent (check the determinant of your matrix, without the extra column)

You will only have a linear combination $ae_1+be_2+ce_3 = v$ whenever $v \in <e_1, e_2, e_3>$, which is not the case here.

If your vectors were linearly independent, then $dim(<e_1, e_2, e_3>)=3$, therefore $<e_1, e_2, e_3>=\mathbb{R}^3$, and you would have that (unique) linear combination for any vector

Answer (score 0):

Rather than convert to matrix form, I would start from the definition of "linear combination".  To write <2, -5, 3> as a linear combination of <1, -3, 2>, <2, -4, -1>, and <1, -5, 7> we seek numbers a, b, c such that a<1, -3, 2>+ b<2, -4, -1>+ c<1, -5, 7>= = <2, -5, 3>.

That gives the three equations a+ 2b+ c= 2, -3a- 4b- 5c= -5, and 2a- b+ 7c= 3.
Adding twice the first equation to the second eliminates b and leaves -a- 3c= -1.  Adding twice the third equation to the first equation also eliminates b and leaves 5a+ 15c= 8.  Adding 5 times -a- 3c= -1 to 5a+ 15c= 8 eliminates **both** a and c leaving 0= 3, a false equation for all a, b, and c.

There are NO values of a, b, and c that satisfy this, we **cannot** write <-2, -5, 3> as a linear combination of <1, -3, 2>, <2, -4, -1>, and <1, -5, 7>.